# Motorola RAZR D3 power button doesn't (un)lock screen

Tags: lock-screens, buttons, motorola

I have Motorola RAZR D3, and when I press the power button, nothing happens:

- If the device goes to lock screen (after 5s), I can't unlock it with the power button, and the only way is using the soft reset to restart the phone.
- If I press Power + Volume down, the device is restarted after 10s.

Thing I have tried:

- Check *Settings > Security > Power Button instant lock* and it's checked.
- Reset the device with *Settings > Backup & reset > Factory data reset* and I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is *not* the ideal solution, but is still a working solution (bad solution is better than no solution):

Using the reference from [TrendBlog.net](http://trendblog.net/android-power-button-not-working-screen-on-off/), I installed [Power Button to Volume Button](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teliapp.powervolume) which replaces the power button functionality (un/lock screen) with the volume buttons (up & down).

Comment: Thx Andrew for the edit. Btw the final solution was take the device to a Repair Center and the technical change the power contact and the button (it was a hardware issue), but i have another problem too (battery was death) so i have to charge it with a power wired usb cable (search in youtube) after disarm the device :)